# How can I parse large XML files with Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting an “Out of memory” error with Perl's XML::Simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726197/why-am-i-getting-an-out-of-memory-error-with-perls-xmlsimple)

I have a XML file like this:

```
            <message>
                <c1>
                    <rrcConnectionSetupComplete>
                        <rrc-TransactionIdentifier>2</rrc-TransactionIdentifier>
                        <criticalExtensions>
                            <c1>
                                <rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8>
                                    <selectedPLMN-Identity> 1 </selectedPLMN-Identity>
                                    <dedicatedInfoNAS> 07410109014290112345671000028020000f0 </dedicatedInfoNAS>
                                </rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8>
                            </c1>
                        </criticalExtensions>
                    </rrcConnectionSetupComplete>
                </c1>
            </message>
```

I am using Perl code like this to access the data in XML file (I should stick on to this format of accessing)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use XML::Simple;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;

my $data = $xml->XMLin("uL-DCCH-Message.xml");

my $rrc_trans_identifier = $data->{'c1'}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete'}->{'rrc-TransactionIdentifier'};
print "rrc_trans_id :: $rrc_trans_identifier\n";

my $selected_plmn_id = $data->{c1}->{rrcConnectionSetupComplete}->{criticalExtensions}->{c1}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8'}->{'selectedPLMN-Identity'};
print "plmn identity :: $selected_plmn_id\n";

my $rrc_dedicated_info_nas = $data->{c1}->{rrcConnectionSetupComplete}->{criticalExtensions}->{c1}->{'rrcConnectionSetupComplete-r8'}->{dedicatedInfoNAS};
print "dedicated info nas :: $rrc_dedicated_info_nas\n";
```

The output produced is,

```
rrc_trans_id :: 2
plmn identity ::  1
dedicated info nas ::  07410109014290112345671000028020000f0
```

Perl code using XML::Simple is working fine for smaller XML files (as shown in the above output).

But If XML file is large, then XML::Simple cannot handle and it is showing the error message `Ran out of memory`.

Are there any other XML Parsers I can use so that I can access the elements in XML file in the similar manner as shown above?

If there is any other parsers available, can any one give an example by following the same conventions I am following for XML::Simple.

Comment: You already asked this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726197/why-am-i-getting-an-out-of-memory-error-with-perls-xmlsimple -- please re-read the advice you were given there.

Comment: but i asked it in an unclear manner, that s why i am again asking with the exact scenario

Comment: so edit your original question to clarify. Don't spam the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of XML Parsers available:

- simple ones that read the whole XML
  file into memory and generate an easy
  accessible data structure, this takes
  a rather big amount of memory so
  you'll get into trouble with bigger
  files. Their advantage is that they
  are usually very easy to work with.
- the SAX based parsers which process
  the XML element by element. To work
  with this parsers the developer
  (you!) has to register callbacks for
  every interesting element and work
  with the information from the
  callbacks. Everytime the SAX parser
  encounters a given element the
  associated callback is executed and
  you are able to only work with the
  interesting tags rather the whole
  file at once. This parsers keep the
  memory usage (potentially) very low
  but require substatially more work.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is huge then you should use any SAX based parser or try [LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) parser.